# How to improve CMP performance?

Tags: neovim, performance, plugin-nvim-cmp

nvim-cmp + Tailwind LSP lags the crap out of the editor when typing HTML class names.

I understand this must be because Tailwind's suggestions come in large quantities.

But is there a way to improve this?

My config is pretty minimal and it's already slower than VSCode. I must be doing something wrong.

My config: [link](https://github.com/brunobragaw8t/nvim-2)

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not even understood the question

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue by using someone's fork of cmp that targetered this specific issue.

https://github.com/yioneko/nvim-cmp

The suggestions seem to have some delay before showing up, but they don't lag the typing.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
  -- create a treshhold for big files
  local preferred_sources = {
    { name = "luasnip" },
    { name = "nvim_lsp" },
    { name = "nvim_lua" },
    { name = "path" },
  }

  local function tooBig(bufnr)
    local max_filesize = 10 * 1024 -- 100 KB
    local check_stats = (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat
    local ok, stats = pcall(check_stats, vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(bufnr))
    if ok and stats and stats.size > max_filesize then
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
  vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufRead", {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("CmpBufferDisableGrp", { clear = true }),
    callback = function(ev)
      local sources = preferred_sources
      if not tooBig(ev.buf) then
        sources[#sources + 1] = { name = "buffer", keyword_length = 4 }
      end
      cmp.setup.buffer({
        sources = cmp.config.sources(sources),
      })
    end,
  }) -- create a treshhold for big files (end)
```

Also try this:

```lua
    performance = {
      max_view_entries = 7,
    },
```